# Wheel will not come off, may be bent around hub

Tags: wheels

The wheel of my 1997 Grand Caravan will not come off. I have tried banging it with a hammer, kicking it while sitting on the concrete, prying it with a pry bar, and loosening the nuts and driving the van back and forth a couple of times while hammering the brakes. Still can't get it to come off! Any suggestions would help. I have a roofing torch attached to propane -- will heating the wheel up help? I don't want to have to tow it anywhere to get it fixed.

Comment: What kind of hammer did you hit it with?  Where did you hit with the hammer?

Comment: Steel wheel or fancy aluminum?

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you're doing all the right things. Wheels sticking to hubs is caused by corrosion between the two, and is usually worse with alloys as the metals are dissimilar.

The best technique I have found is to loosen the nuts, then hit the front face of the tyre in a repeated star pattern (i.e. move around the face of the wheel by about 100 degrees each time, so you're constantly hitting in a different place) until you break the seal - this may take some time! Hitting the tyre rather than the wheel avoids the risk of cracking the wheel (alloys can be quite weak to shock impact - steels will be fine), and imparts more of a twist than hitting near the hub.

Comment: I like a 3--4 foot length of pressure treated 6x6" post as a battering ram. If possible, hit the bottom edge of the wheel/tire from the inside of the vehicle. As Nick said, don't remove the nuts/bolts completely. Penetrating oil can help as well.

Comment: I always found hitting the tire from the inside with my usual metal pipe that serves as a breaker bar works well.

Answer (score 1):

I will give you an insane suggestion so it is up to you that you want to try it or not

Loosen all the nut's o the tire. Lift your car using a jack, spray some kind of lubricant's to the bolt socket's as to get rid of rust in there and now try to pull tires out, if not work try to hammer it out if this also fails tie a rope to the tire and pull it with other car, don't use bike as it could end up damaging you body haha